# Connect three buildings nearby in a single WiFi network

Tags: wireless

There are three small buildings, around 100 feet (30 meters) apart from each. 100mb/s internet endpoint is in the window of the second floor of the main building. I drew a scheme in scale:

[image]

Equipment that is currently used:

- Router [Asus RT-N66U](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006QB1RPY) in the window main building.
- Router [Asus RT-N10U](http://www.amazon.co.uk/RT-N10U-Wireless-Router-Repeater-Access/dp/B006JFY72C) in the window of the secondary building.

Currently, routers are connected via repeater mode.
Both routers are indoor, but antenna of the second router is extended outdoor via an antenna cable. If the antenna is placed indoor, it does not pick up a signal from the main building at all.

My goal is to get wifi in the workshop. I can not use cables or powerline adapters. Currently, I can barely get a signal outdoor of the workshop (from secondary building router).

Please recommend, should I buy a third router or antenna? And what the ideal place to put it? Or should I just throw away current routers and buy more powerful equipment (e.g. Ubiquiti)?

Thank you.

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. WiFi is for portable devices mostly, all other should be connected with wired lines. Including your buildings.

Comment: Questions about consumer-grade equipment, such as your Asus router/firewall/WAP combination devices, are explicitly off-topic here. You should try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

If you have a direct line of sight between the three buildings, you could try a DIY directional WiFi antenna, made from an old satilite dish.

Or build your own wifi cell tower.

Comment: In many jurisdictions, including the U.S., that would be illegal.

Comment: @RonMaupin really? illegal? that doesnt make much sense, except the own cell tower bit... using 2 directional attenas is a very sane idea...

Comment: @silverpenguin The FCC imposes maximum antenna gain. A system must meet the FCC regulations for amplifier power and antenna gain. Using antennae which haven't been certified is illegal in the U.S.

Comment: @silverpenguin, see the limits in [this PDF](http://www.air802.com/files/FCC-Rules-and-Regulations.pdf). Point-to-point regulations are a bit more relaxed than multi-point regulations, but the consequences of getting caught with DYI antennae which exceed the regulations can be pretty severe, and they include confiscation of all the equipment and large fines.

Comment: @RonMaupin interesting, with my work with wireless in aviation I know there are some powers, frequencies and channels which are limited in many countries. though having a reasonable gain shouldnt be to much of an  issue.. 2 legal gain attenas should be enough for this distance

Comment: @silverpenguin, Yes, legal gain antennae should work, but I was commenting on the "_DIY directional WiFi antenna, made from an old satilite[sic] dish_."

Comment: ahh i understand

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 options as far as I see it:

1: VPN connect to each building using a VPN and share the configuration that way.

2: Mesh networks, using multiple APs you can create a mesh network creating hops for distances (though normally used for large buildings with little Ethernet cables available to use)

3: direction attena aiming at another directional attena and creating a link there either as a local VPN or very secure 802.x ...

4: a long subterranean cable. ethernet cables lose their usefulness at 100m. 30m is ok